# Emacs refuses to save file: "File has changed on disk". Really, emacs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, emacs

When I edit a file in Emacs on my Ubuntu Linux system and try to save, I sometimes see the message:

```
File foo.txt has changed on disk. Really save?
```

The weird thing is that I haven't changed it on disk, I'm just editing it in Emacs and nothing else. I've saved it myself a minute ago and that should be its last state. So some other process must be touching it behind my back, while I'm editing it.

Of course I can tell Emacs to save anyway, but I'm just curious why the file has allegedly changed without my knowledge.

Does anyone know this problem? What is a likely cause? Or is it possibly an Emacs bug?

Comment: What file? Is it a file in particular?

Comment: It is just some random text file I am editing in my home directory, e.g. `$HOME/foo.txt`.

Comment: Does the file has *really* changed or just *touched* (changed the time stamps)?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't check. I assume just the time stamp has changed for some reason ...

Comment: I don't know if this is a related problem, but sometimes it takes about a second or two to save a file ... :-(

Comment: Have you tried opening 2 terminal windows side by side and while you edit the foo.txt file in one terminal window, run "tail -f foo.txt" in the other terminal window to see if another process is indeed the culprit?

Comment: @ricbax: Good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: I would try to set a trap using inotify.

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing remote files on ftp server it is definitely clock sync problem. You have different time from remote host. Solution for that is to setup ntpd and sync it. That is how I solved my problem with remote host. Didn't have that kind of problems with local file editing.